# How do I copy Excel workbook filename into cell using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

Using PowerShell, I would like to open an Excel workbook, copy the name of the workbook then paste that name into a cell (G6) on one of the worksheets (Jpl) within that workbook. Save & close.

```
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\MyExcelfiles\GR-E"
$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.visible=$False
$xl.displayalerts = $False

foreach($File in $Files){
 
$baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.fullname)
Write-Host $baseName
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file, $null, $true)
$worksheet = $wb1.sheets.item("Jpl")
$bookname = $wb1.Range("G6")
$bookname.PasteSpecial(-4163)
$wb1.Save()
$wb1.Close()
 
}
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: So please tell us what does not work with your solution. Any Error messages? PLease add these in full to your question.  BTW Did you know PowerShell adds a very handy property to the FileInfo objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` called `BaseName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. See comments in code for explanation.

```
#Added the -File switch since you only want files.
#also added a filter for only excel files
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\Test\Excel" -File -Filter "*.xls?"

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.visible=$False
$xl.displayalerts = $False

foreach($File in $Files) {
 
  Write-Host $File.baseName

  #Open file using fully qualified Path
  $wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file.FullName)

  $worksheet = $wb1.sheets("Jpl")

  #Couldn't get Range method to work switched to Cells
  $Worksheet.Cells(6,"G") = $File.BaseName

  $wb1.Save()
  $wb1.Close()
 
}

$xl.Quit()
```

Console Output using 2 test files:

```
JPLTest-1
JPLTest-A
```

One of the files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help RG.  Worked nicely!

Comment: IMat, glad to be of assistance, keeps the mind sharp.